# Read, Get, Compare and Count Rows from GridView VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, compare, rows

i have a little problem and actually i can't get out from his.. I have a column called 'Periodicidade' that gives me how many times must a thing get done.

What i want to do is a validation that it will count how many times exists one of them, and if one of them have the radiobutton fill, it will force the user to fill the others of the same type of periocidade, but in the moment he is counting the total gridview rows, and not the type of same periodicidade. My current code is:

```
    Dim todos_items_periocidade_vazios As Boolean = True
    Dim todos_items_periocidade_preenchidos As Boolean = False
    Dim periocidade_validada As Boolean = False

    'quantas linhas tem a grid
    Dim n_linha_grid As Integer = GridView_Manutencao.Rows.Count
    Dim periocidade_linha As String
    Dim contador_preenchido As Integer = 0
    Dim contador_linhas As Integer = 0
    'para cada linha verificar 
    For Each row2 As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows

        'percorrer tabela e validar a periocidade da linha encontrada
        periocidade_linha = (CType(row2.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text)

        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows
            If ((CType(row.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text) = periocidade_linha) Then
                contador_linhas = contador_linhas + 1
                periocidade_validada = True
                If periocidade_validada = True Then
                    'testar se está vazio ou preenchido
                    If (CType(row.FindControl("RBList"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue = "") Then
                        'percorrer a tabela e verificar se todos os itens estão vazios ou não
                        For Each row1 As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows
                            If ((CType(row1.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text) = periocidade_linha) Then
                                If (CType(row1.FindControl("RBList"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue = "") Then
                                    todos_items_periocidade_vazios = True
                                Else
                                    todos_items_periocidade_vazios = False
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    Else
                        For Each row1 As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows
                            If ((CType(row1.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text) = periocidade_linha) Then
                                If (CType(row1.FindControl("RBList"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue <> "") Then
                                    contador_preenchido = contador_preenchido + 1
                                    todos_items_periocidade_preenchidos = True
                                Else
                                    todos_items_periocidade_preenchidos = False
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If


                End If






            End If
        Next
        valida_comentario()


        If contador_preenchido = 0 Then
            periocidade_validada = False
            tudo_validado = False
        ElseIf contador_preenchido < contador_linhas Then
            periocidade_validada = False
            tudo_validado = False
        Else
            If valida_comentario() = True Then
                If ((todos_items_periocidade_vazios = True) And (todos_items_periocidade_preenchidos = True)) Then
                    periocidade_validada = True
                    tudo_validado = True
                    Lbl_Mensagem.Text = "Registo inserido com sucesso!"
                ElseIf ((todos_items_periocidade_vazios = False) And (todos_items_periocidade_preenchidos = True)) Then
                    periocidade_validada = True
                    tudo_validado = True
                    Lbl_Mensagem.Text = "Registo inserido com sucesso!"
                Else
                    periocidade_validada = False
                    tudo_validado = False
                    Lbl_Mensagem.Text = "Erro"
                End If
            Else
                tudo_validado = False
                periocidade_validada = False
                Lbl_Mensagem.Text = "Erro"

            End If

        End If

    Next

    Return periocidade_validada
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer, hope to be useful to all of you, thanks, here it goes:

```
   Dim texto_periodicidade As String
    Dim valor As String
    Dim flag_validacao As Boolean = False
    Dim contador_falso As Integer
    contador_falso = 0
        For Each linha As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows
            texto_periodicidade = CType(linha.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text
            valor = CType(linha.FindControl("RBList"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue

            For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView_Manutencao.Rows
                If (texto_periodicidade = CType(row.FindControl("Label_Periodicidade"), Label).Text) Then
                If (valor = CType(row.FindControl("RBList"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue) Then
                    flag_validacao = True
                Else
                    contador_falso = contador_falso + 1
                    flag_validacao = False
                End If
                End If




        Next row

    Next linha
    If contador_falso > 0 Then
        Lbl_Mensagem.Text = "Complete os restantes valores da periocidade!"
        contador_falso = 0
        Return False
    Else
        If valida_comentario() = True Then
            contador_falso = 0
            Return True

        End If
    End If
```